# Big O Notation of a certain algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

I have the following algorithm that determines the greatest common divisor of two numbers x and y. I need to find the big o notation that describes this algorithm and explain why, but I have no idea how to do this.

Could someone please look at my code and explain what type of big oh notation it would be?

```
     public void question1(int x, int y){
            ArrayList divisorx = new ArrayList(); //the list of divisors of number x
            ArrayList divisory = new ArrayList();//divisors of number y
            ArrayList answerSet = new ArrayList();//the common divisors from both   
            //divisorx and divisory

            for(int i=1; i<=x; i++){//this loop finds the divisors of number x and 
                                    //adds them to divisorx
                    double remainder = x%i;
                    if(remainder==0){
                        //i is a divisor
                        divisorx.add(i);
                    }
            }
            for(int i2=1; i2<=y; i2++){//this loop finds the divisors of number y 
                                       //and adds them to divisory
                    double remainder2 = y%i2;
                    if(remainder2==0){
                        //i2 is a divisor
                        divisory.add(i2);
                    }
            }
      int xsize = divisorx.size();
      int ysize = divisory.size();

            for(int i=0; i<xsize; i++){//this massive loop compares each element of 
        //divisorx to those of divisory to find common divisors. It adds those common
        //divisors to the arraylist answerSet
               for(int j=0; j<ysize; j++){
                   if(divisorx.get(i)==divisory.get(j)){
                       //common divisor has been found
                       //add it to an answer array

                       answerSet.add(divisorx.get(i));

                   }
                }
            }
    Collections.sort(answerSet);//sorts the answerSet from smallest to greatest

    Object gcd = answerSet.get(answerSet.size()-1);//get the last element of the
                                                   //arraylist, which is the gcd       
    System.out.print("Your Answer: "+gcd);//print out the greatest common divisor
 }
```

Comment: Have a look at the loops and the Operations. E.g. you `sort` a collection sortingcosts at least *O(n log n)*

Comment: One place to start is to count how many times each line of code is executed.. Many lines are only executed once, so you mostly need to pay close attention to loops. In this particular case, your "counting" will be in terms of x and y.

Comment: The important thing when you compute something like this is to look at the number of bits that each number is. Doing the analysis in terms of the magnitude is trickier.

Comment: There are many operations that can be cleaned very easily in the above algorithm. For example rather than going from 1->x you can do x->2. That will eliminate the nested loop and replace sort by a small merge-like operation. Even if you don't implement the Euclidean method the current code seems like a way to slow down the blunt way as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The largest **complexity** is the *two nested for-loops* that you have. **Big O** is *order* and means it is the complexity relative to the input size. Here your input size is number of divisors which you find in linear time (1 for-loop each) meaning `n + n` or `O(n)`. The sorting in your example is usually of average complexity of `n*log(n)`. Your nester for-loops are square meaning `O(n^2)`. Your order is then the `O(n^2)` because this is the largest complexity in computation. We take the largest degree in the polynomial expression that we get of adding all the complexities so `O(n^2 + n*log(n) + 2n)` which is 2nd degree polynomial and thus ~ `O(n^2)`.

**It should be noted that the order is the larger complexity of space and time. So if memory usage complexity is larger than computational complexity then that takes over.**

Comment: You forgot the sort on `answerSet` as well

Comment: Sure that's usually nlog(n) I will add it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. However, I thought that because Big O looked at the worst-case, it would see that the Collections.sort() has a run time that represents O(nlog(n)). So wouldn't the final answer really be O(nlog(n))?

Comment: @GeorgioMahugana The O(n²) term beats the O(n log n) term. However with closer bounds neither of those terms end up being dominant (see my answer). Also note that you can apply Big O notation to other kinds of complexity analysis than worst-case, e.g best-case complexity.

Answer (score 2):

First two loops have cost **O(X)** and **O(Y)**, respectively.

Number of divisors of N is O(sqrt(N)) (see comments), so xsize and ysize are O(sqrt(X)) and O(sqrt(Y)).

Your last loop therefore has cost **O(sqrt(X).sqrt(Y))**.

`answerSet` has size O(min(sqrt(X),sqrt(Y))) since it is the intersection of `divisorx` and `divisory`.

You perform a sort on answerSet, which is **O(min(sqrt(X),sqrt(Y)) log(min(sqrt(X),sqrt(Y)))**

All of those are O(X+Y), so total complexity is **O(X+Y)**.

Comment: You're not taking into account the sort at the end.

Comment: Re-edited, as `answerSet` is O(N), the sort is O(N log N) which is lower than O(N²)

Comment: Edited once more, with a closer bound on the number of divisors

Comment: The number of divisors of N is not sqrt(N). Take 2: it has 2 divisors (1 and 2).

Comment: Big O notation is about asymptotical behaviour

Comment: @Khaur Yes but it gives a upper bound. What you are saying is that 'the highest number of divisors a number N can have is sqrt(N)', that is false.

Comment: @Simon I didn't say that 'the highest number of divisors a number N can have is sqrt(N)', I said this number is O(sqrt(N)). Those are different statements.

Comment: For a given N>=1, there is only 1 integer that can both divide N and be greater than sqrt(N), and it is N itself. So N has at most sqrt(N)+1 divisors, which is O(sqrt(N))

Comment: @Khaur Oh, I got what you are saying. But it is useless, because the lists store ALL the divisors, we don't care about the highest. We want to know 'how many divisors a number N can have?' The answer is: at most N.

Comment: @Simon There are at most sqrt(N) different integers in the interval [1,sqrt(N)]

Comment: @MikeSamuel if x or y is zero then the for loop won't even run once so `if(remainder==0){` will never run.

Comment: @Khaur the claim "For a given N>=1, there is only 1 integer that can both divide N and be greater than sqrt(N), and it is N itself" is false. Both 4 and 6 divide 12 but they are both greater than sqrt(12) ~= 3.46.

Comment: Right, I don't know what I was thinking, I got carried away looking for a closer bound... I'll correct everything

Comment: Ok, I looked for another bound on the number of divisors of N and found [this](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=568385), which is O(sqrt(n)) (and for the record along the lines of what I had in mind, I "just" forgot half the divisors). There may be closer bounds, but it doesn't matter since the dominant term ends up being the first two loops. I'll edit again.

Answer (score 0):

First loop is done exactly `X` times.
Second loop `Y` times.
Third loop for sure less than `(X/2 + 1) * (Y/2 + 1)` times (since a number `N` can have at most `N/2 + 1` divisors). So the worst case is `O(XY/4) = O(XY)`.
The same for the size of the list `answerSet`, that can have at most `XY/4` elements.
Finally sorting is done in `O(nlogn)` (according to javadoc), that is, in your case, `O(XYlog(XY))`.
So the final complexity is `O(X + Y + XY + XYlog(XY)) = O(XYlog(XY))`.
If you want to express the complexity with only a generic `N`, then it is `O((N^2)logN)`, where `N = max(X, Y)`.

Comment: If you look at the third loop on a semantic level, you'll see that you can get a closer min(X,Y) bound on `answerSet`

Comment: @Khaur Yes, I saw and I deleted my previous comment. Anyway, according to what you are saying, the complexity is `O(X + Y + XY + NlogN)`. How can you compare `XY` and `NlogN`?